# about decltype in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, decltype

I've to implement a protocol communication with a device throw serial port. The protocol is binary based where we have an header that containt the kind and the length of the packet, an optional body and a checksum.

I'm using C++11 with Visual C++ 2012 with the v110_xp toolset.

My first attempt to implement it is using the following class:

`PacketOutA`, `PacketOutB`, `PacketOutC` are all classes with a common interface, they have just two method: `begin()` and `end()` to access internal data;

I have an interface for response packet `IPacketIn`, a derived class `PacketIn` the implement common staff and the derivates `PacketInA`, `PacketInB` and so on.

The class `Communication` is used to allow me to send and recieve data to the communication port.

The `ReaderAndValidator` class allow me to get validate the recieved packet and get the body.

`Dispatcher< T >` is used to get the corrisponding input packet from the requestç

```
PacketInA doPacketA()
{
    PacketA packetA;
    Dispatcher< PacketA > disp( communication );
    PacketInA result = controller.send( packetA );
    return result; // RVO
}
```

Let's look the snippet of the code:

```
class Communication {
public:

    Communication ();

    template < typename Iterator >
    void send( Iterator first, Iterator last ) const
    {
        // send from first to last to 
    }

    template< typename Iterator >
    std::vector< char > read( Iterator first, Iterator last ) const
    {
        // read from first to last to 
    }

private:
    // internal stuff
};

class ReaderAndValidator{
public:

    ReaderAndValidator( const Communication& comm )
        : mComm( comm )
    {
    }

    std::vector< char > read()
    {
        // read data
        return mComm.read( /* params */ );
    }

private:
    const Communication& mComm;
}

template < typename PacketOut >
class Dispatcher{
    Dispatcher()
    {
        static_assert( false, "unable to instantiate Controller" );
    }
};

template <>
class Dispatcher< PacketOutA > {
public:
    Dispatcher( const Communication& comm )
        : mComm( comm )
    {
    }

    PacketInA send( const PacketOutA & packet ) const
    {
        mComm.send( std::begin( packet ), std::end( packet ) );

        ReaderAndValidator readAndValidate( mComm );
        auto body = readAndValidate.read();

        // RVO
        PacketInA result( std::begin( body ), std::end( body ) );
        return result;
    }

private:
    const Communication& mComm;
};

// same thing for Dispatcher< PacketOutB >, Dispatcher< PacketOutC > and so on
```

The class `Device` abstract the operation that I can do on my device

```
class Device : private boost::noncopyable {
public:

    Device ()
    {
        // init communication
    }

    void doPacketOutA( int param )
    {
        PacketOutA packet( param );
        recieve( packet );
    }

    PacketInB doPacketB()
    {
        PacketOutB packet();
        return recieve( packet );
    }

private:

    template < typename PacketOutKind >
    auto recieve( const PacketOutKind& p ) -> decltype( Dispatcher< PacketOutKind >::send( p ) )
    {
        Dispatcher< PacketOutKind > disp( mCommunication );
        return controller.send( p );
    }

private:

    Communication mCommunication;
};
```

But I have a problem with the recieved method: how can I deduce the return type in this situation?

Is this design a good choice? Are better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `send()` function is not static, so you need an instance to invoke it on.

You can use [`std::declval<>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to create a dummy instance - it's an unevaluated context, and `declval()` does just a cast to a reference type, so the class won't really be instantiated:

```
#include <utility>

template < typename PacketOutKind >
    auto receive( const PacketOutKind& p ) -> 
//          ^^
//          Totally unrelated spelling issue :)
        decltype( std::declval< Controller< PacketOutKind > >().send( p ) )
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow this is the fastes response I ever seen. It now compiles thank you.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Yes, I think it is acceptable. Of course there are alternatives, but this choice looks OK to me.

Comment: Maybe I can make recieved packet not deriving from anything... With this design I haven't polymorphism nor need to derivate from anything

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Perhaps a better place where to discuss possible improvements to some concrete already working program would be [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Personally, I would say don't use inheritance if you don't need it ;) (in this answer I just covered the point about `decltype`, I did not have time to inspect the rest of the code)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I ignored the existence of declval... I'll learn it better.